# converting date in to second in excel

Tags: excel, date, converters

In attached link there is an image of excel file. I would like to convert date and time in to seconds. I am using below mentioned formula for that.

for sec:

```
 =(STUNDE(A243) * 3600 + MINUTE(A243) * 60 + SEKUNDE(A243))
     -(STUNDE($A$11) * 3600 + MINUTE($A$11) * 60 + SEKUNDE($A$11))
```

for hr:

```
 =B243/3600
```

but If you see in sheet, my values become minus when the date is changed from 13 to 14. How I can make it in positive?

[image: enter Data sheet]

Comment: Please avoid posting data in screenshots, because that makes it impossible  to copy it for people who want to test your code. You should instead make a table in your question and paste a sample of the data inside it.

Comment: @GPhilo I think posting Excel data in screen shots is fine. Otherwise it is difficult to see what cell ranges to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the time value to seconds but also subtracting the time value in `A11` - I can't see `A11` in your screenshot but from the values shown you can calculate that `A11` has the time value `16:54:57` (and presumably a date?), so whenever the time value in a cell is lower than that the result is negative.

What are you trying to achieve? What result do you expect in row `251`?

If you just want elapsed seconds since the date/time in `A11` then use this formula for `B243` copied down to always get a positive result

`=(A243-A$11)*86400`

Format `B243` as general or number with no decimals

That takes the difference between `A243` and `A11` and multiplies by the number of seconds in a day to give the result in seconds

Your elapsed hours formula can stay the same

Answer (score 0):

The formula to make something positive in Excel is called `=ABS()`.

[ABS MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/abs-function).
It takes a value and it makes sure the output is positive. Give it a try.

Comment: ABS is used for finding the absolute time. Instead of showing date in negative, it''ll show the difference between two dates